# Getting a C error that I have an undefined reference to function, but the function is defined

Tags: c, makefile

I am trying to take a binary to decimal function out of my main.c file and into its own file, but when I compile the files with my makefile I get the error:

```
undefined reference to `btod'
```

Here is my main.c file:

```
#include "btod.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("\nEnter a binary number: ");
    char c[100];
    scanf("%s",c);
    printf("Number converted to decimal: %d\n\n\n",btod(strlen(c),c));
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my btod.c file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int btod(int size,char inputBin[size])
{
    int i,num=0;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        num=num*2+(inputBin[i]-48);
    }
    return num;
}
```

Here is my btod.h file:

```
int btod(int size,char inputBin[size]);
```

And lastly, here is my makefile:

```
CC = gcc
INCLUDE = -I.
CFLAGS = -g -Wall
LDFLAGS = -L. \
    -L/usr/lib
LDLIBS = \
    -lc -lm
.c.o:
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
all: main
main: main.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)
btod: btod.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f main
```

I am thinking it might have to do with the btod.c file not being compiled properly within the makefile but I cannot figure out what is incorrect about it.

Comment: remove `btod:` section and make the other one `main: main.o btod.o`

Comment: Your makefile could be [simplified](https://gist.github.com/pileon/9e72bc962ac5e2906f119b4b31ee2550) quite a lot.

Comment: Also please try to avoid [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If by `48` you mean the ASCII value for `'0'`, use the actual character `'0'` instead. And you should probably add some validation to make sure the input string really is only `'0'` and `'1'`. And to make sure you don't overflow the result `num`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because you don't link in `btod.o` when building `main`.  If you use GNU Make, you can simplify your Makefile to just a few lines:

```
.PHONY: all clean
CFLAGS = -g -Wall

all: main

clean:
    rm -f *.o main

main: btod.o main.o
```

In btod.c use '0' instead of 48.  In main.c remove the line `int n`.

Comment: this fixed my problem, thank you! and I appreciate the other suggestions as well, very helpful